# ReactJS - how can I distinguish which option in select attribute I want to display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have two arrays:

```js
const devices = [{
  deviceName: 'Pierwszy',
  deviceId: 10
}, {
  deviceName: 'Drugi',
  deviceId: 20
}, {
  deviceName: 'Trzeci',
  deviceId: 30
}, {
  deviceName: 'Czwarty',
  deviceId: 40
}, {
  deviceName: 'Piaty',
  deviceId: 50
}];
```

```js
const wires = [{
  wireName: 'First',
  wireId: 10,
  wireLength: 50,
}, {
  wireName: 'Second',
  wireId: 20,
  wireLength: 4,
}, {
  wireName: 'Third',
  wireId: 30,
  wireLength: 87,
}, {
  wireName: 'Fourth',
  wireId: 40,
  wireLength: 5,
}, {
  wireName: 'Fifth',
  wireId: 50,
  wireLength: 1
},
];
```

And I've created my `CustomSelect` component to display options for passed value.

```js
import React from 'react';

class CustomSelect extends React.Component {

  state = {
    optionList: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      optionList: this.props.optionList
    })
  }

  selectMenuOptions = () => {
    return (
      this.state.optionList.map((option, i) => {
        return (
          <option
            key={i}
            value={(option.wireName || option.wireLength) || option.deviceName}
          >
            {option.wireName || option.deviceName || option.wireLength}
          </option>
        )
      })
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select
        name={this.props.name}
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        id={this.props.id}
      >
        {this.selectMenuOptions()}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomSelect;
```

And now, in my `App.js` component I loop over both arrays to display values on the screen, and for every object array I want 3 `select`- for `device` I would like to select different name - so basically change it's name, for `wire` I would like to change also his name, but also `wireLength`. My question is, in my `CustomSelect` component in `option` attribute how can I set `value` to show data I want to show ?

[edit]
Changing only names works, now I want to add way to change also wireLength.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, in my `CustomSelect` component in option attribute how can I set value to show data I want to show ?

You can pass the property name to `CustomSelect` as a prop, and then use this when setting the value:

```
value={option[this.props.valueProp]}
```

So if you have `<CustomSelect ... valueProp="wire" />`, that'll use `option.wire`. If you have `<CustomSelect ... valueProp="wireLength" />`, that'll use `option.wireLength`.

Comment: @Baniak - My pleasure! The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable) will probably be helpful as well.

Comment: I'm starting to learn react, I know props system, but I'm unaware of how powerful it is and how many "complicated" problems can be solved in very simple way, like sending for every component different names :) And of course, yours solution works, asap I'll mark it as solved :)